# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects when placing the custom url in scrapy.Request()

Tags: python, scrapy

I get a url that cannot be used to fetch data from next page, so created a `base_url = 'http://www.marinetraffic.com'` variable and passed it scrapy request. `port_homepage_url = base_url +  port_homepage_url`.  It works fine, when i yeild the result like this. `yield {'a': port_homepage_url, 'b':item['port_name']}` 
I get this result i wanted.

http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/ships/range/port_id:20585/port_name:FUJAIRAH%20ANCH,FUJAIRAH ANCH

however if place it in scrapy request `yield scrapy.Request(port_homepage_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'item': item})` i get error

```
port_homepage_url = base_url +  port_homepage_url
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

here is code

```
class GetVessel(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "getvessel"
    allowed_domains = ["marinetraffic.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/ports/all/flag:AE',
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        item = VesseltrackerItem()
        base_url = 'http://www.marinetraffic.com'
        for ports in response.xpath('//table/tr[position()>1]'):
            item['port_name'] = ports.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
            port_homepage_url = ports.xpath('td[7]/a/@href').extract_first()
            port_homepage_url = base_url +  port_homepage_url
            yield scrapy.Request(port_homepage_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'item': item})
```

Comment: `ports.xpath('td[7]/a/@href').extract_first()` is returning None, that's for sure. Can't tell why, though

Comment: You need to make sure your variables actually have values before just passing them to a function - not checking the returned value of a function call isn't usually a good idea. Your real problem, as @lucasnadalutti said, is that your regex isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not happen on the initial start URL page, but happens later on when subsequent requests are processed. Take for example [this page](http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/ships/range/port_id:1699/port_name:HAMRIYA). There are no links in the 7-th `td` element and, hence, `ports.xpath('td[7]/a/@href').extract_first()` returns `None` which results in a failure on the `port_homepage_url = base_url +  port_homepage_url` line.

How to approach the problem depends on what were you planning to do on the "port" pages. From what I understand, you did not mean to actually handle the "port" page requests with `self.parse` and need to have a separate callback with different logic inside.

Comment: yes i had typed the function name in callback function wrong .|
`
yield scrapy.Request(port_homepage_url, callback=self.parse_port_homepage, meta={'item': item})
`